# JPA Buddy missing from Tool Window in Intellij

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, jpa-buddy

After latest update of IntelliJ, **JPA Buddy** missing from right title bar which usually placed under Maven section.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Refer to the docs: https://www.jpa-buddy.com/documentation/. You need to have the dependencies configured in a project and open any Entity class in the editor for all the palettes to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the installation, I hadn't included the right hibernate version and also hadn't updated since I added .

Answer (score 4):

To see the JPA Buddy tool windows you need:

1. Make sure you have hibernate-core, EclipseLink or Spring Data JPA dependency: https://www.jpa-buddy.com/documentation/#dependencies. Also make sure it is correct and reimport dependencies.
2. Make sure you haven't enabled the minimalistic mode: https://www.jpa-buddy.com/documentation/minimalistic-mode/#enabling-minimalistic-mode
3. After the major IntelliJ IDEA update, make sure you updated JPA Buddy and restarted an IDE.
4. Contact the JPA Buddy team on discord if the first two didn't help: https://discord.gg/DxRDQPk9rh.