# JPABUDDY tabs not appear in my intellij project

Tags: intellij-idea

I've installed intellij CE with jpabuddy but jpa buddy not appears to be working in my current project.

This is my current pom.xml dependencies section

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>easy-random-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is my current IDE right panel... as you can see JPA Palette is missing.

I'm running IntelliJ in a Kubuntu 22.04

[image]

[image: Installed Plugin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research on this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974527/jpa-buddy-missing-from-tool-window-in-intellij#:~:text=To%20see%20the%20JPA%20Buddy,is%20correct%20and%20reimport%20dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974527/jpa-buddy-missing-from-tool-window-in-intellij#:%7E:text=To%20see%20the%20JPA%20Buddy,is%20correct%20and%20reimport%20dependencies) and some insights in the JPA BUDDY discord I've finally get the issue: It was running in **minimalistic mode**.

You can disable it following the documentation at its home page:

https://www.jpa-buddy.com/documentation/minimalistic-mode/#enabling-minimalistic-mode

Comment: Thanks to your response, I was able to get JPA Buddy to appear in the sideBar of Intellij. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the install the JPA Buddy plugin to see something in the right panel. Maven JPA dependencies are not enough.

Go to `Preferences->Plugins` and install JPA Buddy from the marketplace.  Restart IntelliJ.

Comment: sorry, i've miss to attach an screenshot of the evidence... i've already have the plugin installed

Comment: No license - does it work without one?  Looks like a paid plugin.  I don't use it myself.  Spring JDBC is enough for me.

Comment: They have free licence with the features I actually need... I have it at work and I love the JPA Pallete, it helps me to create some methods

Comment: Did you restart IntelliJ after installing the plugin?  What about viewing Tool windows?  Is that required to bring it up?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974527/jpa-buddy-missing-from-tool-window-in-intellij#:~:text=To%20see%20the%20JPA%20Buddy,is%20correct%20and%20reimport%20dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo that helped me... For some strange reason it was in minimalistic mode...